# Testing sentence against string of alphabet to see if all letters are in the sentence

Tags: python, algorithm

I am writing an algorithm that takes a user input and sees if it contains all of the characters in the alphabet. For some reason, one of my loops is `true` every iteration and is causing my algorithm not to work. Can anyone help me out?

```
sentence = raw_input()
sentence = sentence.lower()
sentence = sentence.replace(' ', '')
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

if len(sentence) < len(alphabet):
    print 'not pangram'
else:
    for i in range(len(alphabet)):
        for z in range(len(sentence)):
            if alphabet[i] != sentence[z]:
                continue
            else:
                alphabet.replace(alphabet[i], '1')
    if len(alphabet) > 0:
        print 'not pangram'
    else:
        print 'pangram'
    print alphabet
```

Comment: What does it mean for a loop (you can't tell which one?) to be `True`?  In what way(s) is your code's result incorrect (which is what I presume "not to work" means)?

Comment: By the way, the check you want to do is if alphabet is a string containing all `1`s, that is `alphabet == '1'*26`

Comment: Off topic: try `import string` and  `print(string.ascii_lowercase)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve the same result with [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
if set(alphabet) == set(sentence):
    print('pangram')
else:
    print('not pangram')
```

Also you don't need to write alphabet, since it's defined in the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module:

```
import string
if set(string.ascii_lowercase) == set(sentence):
    print('pangram')
...
```

Comment: This is obviously a much more succinct solution. Thank you.

Comment: Wow! I cannot believe how much easier that is. I am trying to search for some good documentation stating how the `set()` function works. Do you know of a good article? I want to understand it.

Comment: It creates a [set (as in mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) from the elements of the sequence. A set does not contain duplicate elements. More documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 2):

You may use `all` function after applying the lower,replace functions.

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz hfashf"
>>> alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> all(i in s for i in alphabet)
True
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstwxyz hfashf"
>>> all(i in s for i in alphabet)
False
>>>
```

You may achieve this through regex also but it's an overkill.

```
re.match(r'(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?c)', s)
```

In the above regex, write upto `z`.. For case insentive match, add `(?i)` at the start.

Comment: Note that this solution is `O(n^2)` (or `O(n*m)` to be exact), so for large strings and alphabets, execution time could be a major issue of this solution compared to the significantly faster alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain what you did wrong.

The `str.replace()` function does not replace strings inplace, it returns a new string with the characters/substrings replaced. In your code, when you are doing - `alphabet.replace(alphabet[i], '1')` , it just replaces the characters and returns back the new string, it does not replace it within the `alphabet` string, since strings are immutable.

You should assign the returned string back to alphabet, also, if you replace the string with `1` its len would never go to 0. Just before checking for `if len(alphabet) == 0:` , you should replace all `1` with empty string - `''` .

```
            else:
                alphabet = alphabet.replace(alphabet[i], '1')
    alphabet = alphabet.replace('1','')
```

Though the others answers are much better and faster ways to achieve your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the length of alphabet in your code does not change, because of:

```
alphabet.replace(alphabet[i], '1')
```

You are just replacing one character with another.

Secondly, your code is a little bit complicated, the simpler solution can be:

```
if len(sentence) < len(alphabet):
    print 'not pangram'
else:
    for letter in sentence:
        alphabet = alphabet.replace(letter, '')
    if len(alphabet) > 0:
        print 'not pangram'
    else:
        print 'pangram'
    print alphabet
```

This code, preserves your idea of replacing the characters, but doing it with an empty string which causes `len(alphabet)` to decrement on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to change the length of `alphabet`, so `len(alphabet) > 0` will always be true.